# sending form data via POST to external website and getting response data in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a list of customer car data which i would like to get more data from [this website](https://vrl.lta.gov.sg/lta/vrl/action/pubfunc?ID=EnquireRebateBeforeDeReg) by filling in the form available there.

I am using PHP and have tried cURL to do so but the response is always empty. I have done all research within my means but still not able to get it. Am i doing it wrongly?

**The code which i used is:**

```
<?php
$vehicleNo='GG8394R';//values from your form
$ownerIdType='1';
$ownerId='S1386629E';
$intendedDeRegDate='29112015';
$exportStatus='Yes';
$yourformfields="vehicleNo=$vehicleNo&ownerIdType=$ownerIdType&ownerId=$ownerId&intendedDeRegDate=$intendedDeRegDate&exportStatus=$exportStatus";
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'https://vrl.lta.gov.sg/lta/vrl/action/enquireRebateByPublicBeforeDeregInput');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$yourformfields);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

if (empty($buffer))
{
    print "Yeah.<p>";
}
else
{
    print $buffer;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added in the line and was able to access the url. But what should i do to submit the POST data to the form here: https://vrl.lta.gov.sg/lta/vrl/action/pubfunc?ID=EnquireRebateBeforeDeReg and getting and saving the response data on my server? Especially with the hidden value and all in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to the websites using HTTPS. By default, curl did not trust any server for HTTPS connection. The quick fix for this is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

You can read more about it [here](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/).

Answer (score 0):

You should add those 2 lines to your code:

```
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```